# Selection of data from two tables Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

These are the tables: `dbo.application`, `dbo.action`, `dbo.ogpo_dept` and `dbo.employees`

```
| ID | dept_id | action | premium |    | ID | Name     |    
------------------------------------    -----------------      
| 1  | 5       | 21     | 61446   |    | 21 | Stiker   |    
| 2  | 11      | 18     | 325     |    | 18 | One Super|
| 3  | 5       | null   | 224     |
| 4  | 11      | 18     | 262     |

| ID | Name               |            | ID | FullName | dept_id |
---------------------------            ---------------------------
| 5  | Sales Dep          |            | 1  | Mike     | 5       |
| 11 | HR Dep             |            | 2  | Ronaldo  | 11      |
```

**My query:**

```
select od.name as dept_name,
       e.Fullname,
       oac.name,
       COUNT(oa.id) as total, 
       SUM(oa.premium) as premSum
from dbo.ogpo_dept od
     inner join dbo.employees e on e.dept_id = od.id
     left join dbo.application oa on oa.dept_id = od.id
     left join dbo.action oac on oac.id = oa.[action]
group by dept_name, e.Fullname, oac.name, oa.[action]
```

The query executes for a long time (doesn't finish).

I tried so, If to remove `SUM (premium) as premSum` that is executed.

I want to receive such result:

```
| Dept_name | FullName | Name     | total | premium |
-----------------------------------------------------
| Sales Dep | Mike     |One Super |68     | 40210   |
| HR Dep    | Ronaldo  |NULL      | 0     | Null    |
```

Comment: If it's not finishing you may be querying against a locked table, if it's just really slow check the execution plan or competing queries.

Comment: @Hart CO, at the end, not to output result

Comment: I try create a sqlfiddle, but your schema doesnt have the same structure as your sample. Could you fix it  for us? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9bc32/2

Comment: @Hart CO, If I add SUM(premium)  then, doesn't work.  If  I clean then, the inquiry works

Comment: That's interesting, doesn't seem like that should make too much difference, let alone break the query.

Comment: I think there isn't summed  null

Comment: How many rows are there in your actual tables?

Comment: @ Chandru, if I clean INNER JOIN dbo.employees(NOLOCK) e ON e.dept_id = od.id then, query works

Comment: Actually what problem you are facing now, it's executing long time or you didn't get the expected result

Comment: @Chandru, the second(there is no result)

Comment: Then provide your expected output based on your example.

Comment: Sales Dep and Hr is not exist in your sample table.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/806b9/3 check this out. your query is working fine. What your are expecting?

Comment: Your sample output is wrong according to your sample data

Comment: Why oa.[action] in the GROUP BY?

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT od.NAME AS dept_name
    ,e.Fullname
    ,oac.NAME
    ,COUNT(oa.id) AS total
    ,SUM(oa.premium) AS premSum
FROM dbo.ogpo_dept WITH (NOLOCK) od
INNER JOIN dbo.employees WITH (NOLOCK) e ON e.dept_id = od.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.application WITH (NOLOCK) oa ON oa.dept_id = od.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.action WITH (NOLOCK) oac ON oac.id = oa.[action]
GROUP BY dept_name
    ,e.Fullname
    ,oac.NAME
    ,oa.[action]
```

Comment: You'll have to provide some more info as to why adding `(NOLOCK)` might work. Also note that the correct notation is `dbo.employees with (NOLOCK)`. Leaving out the `with` has been deprecated.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Agreed with you.